# Releasing related records to free up memory in Yii1

Tags: php, yii, memory-leaks

I have a piece of code that iterates over all the related profile records (HAS_MANY) of a team record.

It looks like this:

```
$team = Team::model()->findByPk(1);
$score = 0;

foreach ($team->profiles as $profile) {
    $score += $profile->getScore();
}
```

Now I need to keep the `$team` variable, but because of the loop all the profiles will be kept in the `profiles` property, and use up a ton of memory.

Is there a way to safely clean this up?
I thought about setting `profiles` to `null`, but then it obviously remains null (and I don't know if another piece of code needs to access `profiles` later on)

Comment: So you want to keep the `$team` variable and at the same time you don't, because it uses a lot of memory? If that's the case I would unset them one by one and just get them from the database again if you need them. Or store them in some kind of temporary file. Don't think there is another way in my opinion.

Comment: No, no. I need to keep the `$team` variable, but I probably don't need to keep the `profiles` property. At least, not for every `$team` record that will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, it seems to me you want to keep the `$team` variable and at the same time you don't, because it uses a lot of memory...

In that case I would unset them one by one:

```
for ($i=0;for ($i=0, $j = count($team->profiles); $i < $j ; ++$i ){
    $score += $team->profiles[$i]->getScore();
    unset($team->profiles[$i]);
}

// OR

foreach ($team->profiles as $key => $profile) {
    $score += $profile->getScore();
    unset($team->profiles[$key]);
}
```

And just get them from the database again if you need them. Or store them in some kind of temporary file. Don't think there is another way in my opinion.